# Convert string to date format in azure data factory using set variable

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-factory

I have string date in set variable "20211222"
And I want to convert it into date like 2021-12-22.
And I have use this function in variable set dynamic content

@formatDateTime('20211222', 'yyyy-MM-dd')

But error occur **In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '20211222' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format**

Is there any other function to convert this string "20211222" into date?

Comment: If ANY answer was helpful , You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), ( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem

Answer (score 2):

Actually the string `'20211222'` is already in the unambiguous format of `YYYYMMDD` and will always be interpreted this way.  If you need to use this string input as a date, just do a cast:

```sql
SELECT CAST('20211222' AS date);  -- 2021-12-22
```

If you wanted to formerly go from your text input `YYYYMMDD` to a text output of `YYYY-MM-DD`, then make a round trip:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), CAST('20211222' AS date), 120);
```

Comment: How I can convert string into date in azure data factory using set variable component?

Answer (score 2):

Function [formatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#formatdatetime) expects "**a string that contains the timestamp**".

Example:

```
formatDateTime('03/15/2018 12:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```

You would have to manage to input in a timestamp format. The default format for the timestamp is "o" (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK), which complies with ISO 8601 and preserves time zone information.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below logic:

```
 @concat(substring(pipeline().parameters.Test,0,4 ),'-',substring(pipeline().parameters.Test,4,2),'-',substring(pipeline().parameters.Test,6,2))
```

Comment: I have solved the problem . Thanks for your effort.